# Python times out after if in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw

> F.W. This isn't just a PRAW question, it leans toward Python more than PRAW. Python people are welcome to contribute, and please note this is not my mother language xD!

Essentially, I'm writing a Reddit bot using the PRAW that does the following:

- Loop through "unsaved" posts
- Loop through the comments of said posts (targeting subcomments)
- If the comment contains "!completed", is written by the submitter OR is a moderator, and the parent comment is not by submitter:
- Do etc., e.x. print("Hey")
  No, I didn't explain that too well. Examples are better, so here xD:

---

### Use cases:

```
- Post by @dudeOne
 - Comment by @dudeTwo
  - Comment with "!completed" by @dudeOne
```

```
- Post by @dudeOne
 - Comment by @dudeTwo
  - Comment with "!completed" by @moderatorOne
```

print("Hey"), and:

```
- Post by @dudeOne
 - Comment by @dudeOne
  - Comment with "!completed" by @dudeOne
```

... does nothing, maybe even removes + messages @dudeOne.

Here's my messy code (xD):

```py
import praw
import os
import re

sub = "RedditsQuests"

client_id = os.environ.get('client_id')
client_secret = os.environ.get('client_secret')
password = os.environ.get('pass')

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=client_id,
                     client_secret=client_secret,
                     password=password,
                     user_agent='r/RedditsQuests bot',
                     username='TheQuestMaster')

for submission in reddit.subreddit(sub).new(limit=None):
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
    if submission.saved is False:
        for comment in submission.comments.list():
            if ((("!completed" in comment.body)) and ((comment.is_submitter) or ('RedditsQuests' in comment.author.moderated())) and (comment.parent().author.name is not submission.author.name)):
              print("etc...")
```

---

There's a decently-sized stack, so I've added it in [this bin](https://pastebin.com/tgJhr9LY) for your reference. To me it looks like PRAW is timing out because the if-in-for loop is taking too long. I could be wrong though!

Comment: Just going by the stack trace, this seems like it's probably a network issue. What environment are you running your program in, and is it possible that some firewall or network restriction may be blocking the connection? Alternatively, does this error happen every time you run the program, or did it just happen once? If it just happened once then it was probably a random fault that shouldn't happen too often.

Comment: @jarhill0 this is running on automated builds (Ubuntu 16.04) every half hour. Returns this response every 1/50 times. Also returns this response on my Ubuntu 18.04. Both on different networks, there are some modifications on my 18.04's network but not on the 16.04's at all.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ran your code and I got the same error as you on the first try. I'll look into this a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue (as you've said) is somewhat sporadic but I've narrowed it down. As it turns out, trying to fetch the subreddits moderated by /u/AutoModerator will sometimes time out (presumably because the list is long).

### Figuring out the issue

Here's how I found the issue. Skip this section if you're only interested in the solution.

First, I modified your script to use `try` and `except` to catch the exception when it happened. Your traceback told me that it was happening on the line that starts with `if ((("!completed" in comment.body))`, specifically when fetching the subreddits that a user moderates. Here was my modified script:

```py
for submission in reddit.subreddit(sub).new(limit=None):
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
    if submission.saved is False:
        for comment in submission.comments.list():
            try:
                if (
                    (("!completed" in comment.body))
                    and (
                        (comment.is_submitter)
                        or ("RedditsQuests" in comment.author.moderated())
                    )
                    and (comment.parent().author.name is not submission.author.name)
                ):
                    print("etc...")
            except Exception:
                print(f'Author: {comment.author} ({type(comment.author)})')
```

And the output:

```
etc...
etc...
Author: AutoModerator (<class 'praw.models.reddit.redditor.Redditor'>)
etc...
etc...
etc...
Author: AutoModerator (<class 'praw.models.reddit.redditor.Redditor'>)
etc...
etc...
etc...
etc...
etc...
etc...
etc...
Author: AutoModerator (<class 'praw.models.reddit.redditor.Redditor'>)
etc...
Author: AutoModerator (<class 'praw.models.reddit.redditor.Redditor'>)
etc...
etc...
```

With this in mind I wrote a very simple 3-line script to reproduce the issue:

```py
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(...)

print(reddit.redditor("AutoModerator").moderated())
```

Sometimes this script would succeed but sometimes it would fail with the same socket read timeout. Presumably the timeout happens because AutoModerator moderates so many subreddits (at least 10,000), and the Reddit API takes too long to process the request.

### Fixing the issue

Your script tries to determine whether the redditor in question is a moderator of the subreddit. You're doing this by checking if the subreddit is in the list of the user's moderated subreddits, but you can switch this to checking if the user is in the list of the subreddit's moderators. Not only should this not time out, but you'll be saving a lot of network requests because you can just fetch the list of moderators once.

[The PRAW documentation of `Subreddit`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.moderator) shows how we can get a list of moderators of a subreddit. In your case, we can do

```py
moderators = list(reddit.subreddit(sub).moderator())
```

Then, instead of checking `"RedditsQuests" in comment.author.moderated()`, we check

```py
comment.author in moderators
```

Your code then becomes

```py
import praw
import os
import re

sub = "RedditsQuests"

client_id = os.environ.get("client_id")
client_secret = os.environ.get("client_secret")
password = os.environ.get("pass")

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    password=password,
    user_agent="r/RedditsQuests bot",
    username="TheQuestMaster",
)

moderators = list(reddit.subreddit(sub).moderator())
for submission in reddit.subreddit(sub).new(limit=None):
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
    if submission.saved is False:
        for comment in submission.comments.list():
            if (
                (("!completed" in comment.body))
                and ((comment.is_submitter) or (comment.author in moderators))
                and (comment.parent().author.name is not submission.author.name)
            ):
                print("etc...")
```

In my brief testing, this script runs many times faster, since we only get the list of moderators once, rather than fetching all subreddits moderated by all users who commented.

---

As an unrelated style note, instead of `if submission.saved is False` you should do `if not submission.saved`, which is the conventional way to check if a condition is false.